# Buffered reader to load in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, actionlistener, bufferedreader

I have made GUI to take the input and to save it. I have trouble when I load input, I have tried to make it with the buffered reader and I am stuck here.

Don't mind the commented areas of code :)

I need help with the load method since I need to input it from array to add input and to move it with prev< and next>.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;


//begining of a class that will implement Action listener
public class Orders extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
 //instance variables, text field and buttons
 private int index;
 JFrame jf;

 JTextField jtfItemName;
 JTextField jtfNumberOf;
 JTextField jtfCost;
 JTextField jtfAmountOwned;

 JButton jbCalculate;
 JButton jbSave;
 JButton jbClear;
 JButton jbExit;

 double calculate;

 JButton jbLoad;
 JButton jbPrev;
 JButton jbNext;

 String itemName;
 String numberOf;
 String cost;
 String amountOwned;

 ArrayList < String > lines;
 String split = ", ";

 //gui implementation

 public Orders() {
  index = 0;
  lines = new ArrayList < > ();
  jf = new JFrame(" Orders Calculator");
  //pannels
  JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
  pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
  JLabel jlFirst = new JLabel("Item name :");
  jlFirst.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
  jtfItemName = new JTextField(10);
  pnl.add(jlFirst);
  pnl.add(jtfItemName);

  JLabel jlSecond = new JLabel("Number of :");
  jlSecond.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
  jtfNumberOf = new JTextField(10);
  pnl.add(jlSecond);
  pnl.add(jtfNumberOf);

  JLabel jlThird = new JLabel("Cost");
  jlThird.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
  jtfCost = new JTextField(10);
  pnl.add(jlThird);
  pnl.add(jtfCost);

  JLabel jlFourth = new JLabel("Amount owned :");
  jlFourth.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
  jtfAmountOwned = new JTextField(10);
  jtfAmountOwned.setEditable(false);
  pnl.add(jlFourth);
  pnl.add(jtfAmountOwned);



  JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

  JPanel jpSouthUp = new JPanel();
  JPanel jpSouthDown = new JPanel();

  jpSouth.add(jpSouthUp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  jpSouth.add(jpSouthDown, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  //buttons top
  jbCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
  jbSave = new JButton("Save");
  jbClear = new JButton("Clear");
  jbExit = new JButton("Exit");
  jpSouthUp.add(jbCalculate);
  jpSouthUp.add(jbSave);
  jpSouthUp.add(jbClear);
  jpSouthUp.add(jbExit);

  //buttons bottom
  jbLoad = new JButton("Load");
  jbPrev = new JButton("<Prev");
  jbNext = new JButton("Next>");

  jpSouthDown.add(jbLoad);
  jpSouthDown.add(jbPrev);
  jpSouthDown.add(jbNext);


  jf.add(pnl);
  jf.add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  jf.pack();
  jf.setVisible(true);
  jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  //action listener
  jbCalculate.addActionListener(this);
  jbSave.addActionListener(this);
  jbClear.addActionListener(this);
  jbExit.addActionListener(this);
  jbLoad.addActionListener(this);
  jbPrev.addActionListener(this);
  jbNext.addActionListener(this);


 }
 public double calc() {
   double number = Double.parseDouble(jtfNumberOf.getText());
   double cost = Double.parseDouble(jtfCost.getText());
   //     double sum = number * cost;
   //    calculate = "" + sum;
   //    jtfAmountOwned.setText(calculate);
   calculate = number * cost;
   jtfAmountOwned.setText(calculate + "");
   return calculate;
  }
  //parametar constructor
 public Orders(String itemName, String numberOf, String cost, String amountOwned) {

  this.itemName = itemName;
  this.numberOf = numberOf;
  this.cost = cost;
  this.amountOwned = amountOwned;


 }

 public void setItemName(String itemName) {
  this.itemName = itemName;
 }

 public String getItemName() {
  return itemName;
 }

 public void setNumberOf(String numberOf) {
  this.numberOf = numberOf;
 }

 public String getNumberOf() {
  return numberOf;
 }

 public void setCost(String cost) {
  this.cost = cost;
 }

 public String getCost() {
  return cost;
 }

 public void setAmountOwned(String amountOwned) {
  this.amountOwned = amountOwned;
 }

 public String getAmountOwned() {
  return amountOwned;
 }




 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent events) {
  if (events.getSource() == jbExit) {
   System.exit(0);
  } else if (events.getSource() == jbClear) {
   jtfItemName.setText("");
   jtfNumberOf.setText("");
   jtfCost.setText("");
   jtfAmountOwned.setText("");
  } else if (events.getSource() == jbCalculate) {
   calc();
  } else if (events.getSource() == jbSave) {

   try {
    PrintWriter pV = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("121lab1.csv", true)));
    pV.println("' " + jtfItemName.getText() + "', " + jtfNumberOf.getText() + ", " + jtfCost.getText() + ", " + calc());
    pV.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("IOExcetion");

   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("General exception");
   }


  } else if (events.getSource() == jbLoad) {
   BufferedReader br = null;
   String line = null;

   try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("121Lab1.csv"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     lines.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",[ ]*")));

    }





   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("IOExcetion");

   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("General exception");
   }

   System.out.println(lines.size());
  } else if (events.getActionCommand().equals("Next>") || events.getActionCommand().equals("<Prev")) {
   move(events.getActionCommand());
  }
 }
 public void move(String where) {
  if (where.equals("Next>")) {
   if ((index + 4) >= lines.size())
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "No more entries");
   else {
    //String[] name = line.split(split);
    //name nameNext = new name();

    /*index = index + 4;
    jtfItemName.setText(lines.get(index));
    jtfCost.setText(lines.get(index+2));
    jtfNumberOf.setText(lines.get(index + 1));
    jtfAmountOwned.setText(lines.get(index + 3));*/
   }
  } else if (where.equals("<Prev")) {
   if ((index - 4) < 0)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "No more entries");
   else {
    /*index = index - 4;
     jtfItemName.setText(lines.get(index));
     jtfCost.setText(lines.get(index+2));
     jtfNumberOf.setText(lines.get(index + 1));
     jtfAmountOwned.setText(lines.get(index + 3));*/
   }
  } else {
   jtfItemName.setText(lines.get(0));
   jtfCost.setText(lines.get(2));
   jtfNumberOf.setText(lines.get(1));
   jtfAmountOwned.setText(lines.get(3));
  }


 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Orders test = new Orders();

 }

}
```

Comment: You could've made a SSCEE.

Answer (score 0):

In your bufferedreader, the filename is 121Lab1.csv. In your bufferedwriter, the filename is 121lab1.csv. You are reading from 121lab1.csv, you are writing to 121Lab1.csv. How do you expect it to work? (reading from nonexistent file)